# numba prints "<NULL>"

Tags: python, numba

I have a jitted python function (`@numba.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)`) that (amongst other things) prints some status variables:

```py
...
for box_index in range(len(box_sizes)):
    ...
    print("The valxue is:", box_sizes_x[box_index])
    ...
```

Recently I modified the code a bit, and now when I run it, I see this:

```
The value is: 0.17
<NULL> 0.34
<NULL> 0.68
<NULL> 1.36
<NULL> 2.72
<NULL> 5.44
<NULL> 10.88
```

the string literals have been replaced by `<NULL>`?! Uh?!

There are no other print statements in the loop. If I add another print statement in the loop, the problem goes away. Also, some of the data calculated in the loop is not coming out how I would expect it when the `<NULL>`s are there, but when I add the extra print statement so the `<NULL>`s disappear, the data comes out looking fine. The values of `box_sizes_x[box_index]` being printed are correct.

What is `<NULL>` and why is it there?

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example. This might be a bug in your code (e.g. UB) or a bug of Numba. The `...` are actually critical parts. Note such thing can sometimes happen when you stop a Numba function with interrupt (since Numba does not support it correctly yet).